# Center aligned group of equations based on ampersand

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

aaa

\vspace{17cm}

\begin{align*}
    \centering
    (a+b)^3 &= (a+b)^2(a+b)\\
    &=(a^2+2ab+b^2)(a+b)\\
    &=(a^3+2a^2b+ab^2) + (a^2b+2ab^2+b^3)\\
    &=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: The important thing is that the relation signs are aligned, not where they are. You're going to get a very unbalanced page.

Comment: This is only an example to show what I want to do, if I end up with a weird page at the end that's another problem

Comment: I've deleted my answer as it apparently didn't meet your needs.

Comment: Why? It was a useful answer, only not the most general one. Besides, I'm not the only person using SE and it can meet the needs of other people

Comment: I don't get the purpose of the hypothetical question you asked me, about how centering adjustments would have to be different if the equations were different. When you present some code, I assume you're (at least) somewhat interested in that code. I see little point in speculating what one might have to do if things, or equations, were different -- especially not if it's quite unclear what "different" may mean.

Comment: No, I wasn't interested in that code, it is just a toy example. It didn't cross my mind that for this case there would be an easier solution (yours). IIRC I didn't even use the word "different" in my comment and I did specify for which case (a pretty common one, not an exception) I couldn't easily find a way to extend your solution. [Example](http://btodcox.org/wp-content/ql-cache/quicklatex.com-f5117bb69ee40ceec338fc44119b3aa9_l3.png) (sure these are not equations but it works the same way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some thing like this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newlength{\mylen}
\settowidth{\mylen}{$(a^3+2a^2b+ab^2) + (a^2b+2ab^2+b^3)$}

\begin{document}

aaa

\vspace{17cm}

\begin{align*}
\mathmakebox[\mylen][r]{(a+b)^3} &= (a+b)^2(a+b)                       \\
                                 &=(a^2+2ab+b^2)(a+b)                  \\
                                 &=(a^3+2a^2b+ab^2) + (a^2b+2ab^2+b^3) \\
                                 &=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Put the LHS inside a box whose width is equal to the widest entry on the right. `\mathmakebox` is provided by `mathtools` package and the contents of this box will be in math mode.

Comment: Marking as correct because this also works when the LHS is not empty in all of the equations